# Xcode - Inferred navigation bar layout issues with tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I am having a very frustrating issue with the layout of tableview when you have an inferred navigation bar.

In order to re-produce this bug

1: Create a navigation based app.

2: Create a 2nd ViewController with XIB file included (In this XIB file, select a top bar to be simulated).

3: On first screen, place a button that when clicked takes you to the new controller created in step 2

4: On new xib file, place a tableview on screen and setup delegate methods.

5: Create a 3rd ViewController with xib file.

Now under didselectrow table delegate method in the 2nd screen, I have it setup to take me to the 3rd screen. However when the app navigates to the new screen, then the back button is pressed, the tableview is pushed down by a height equal to the navigation bar. See images

Originally tableview screen looks like this

[image]

I then select table row, taken to 3rd screen, then press back button, and it then looks like this

[image]

This only happens in XIB files. If I create the same functionality but using storyboard only instead of XIB files, this issue not occur. Now I can fix this by removing the inferred top bar, and instead manually placing a navigation bar in the XIB file. But I shouldn't have to do this each time, as it is annoying.

This only occurs when navigating to a new screen with tableview, if I was to use a button to instead navigate to the 3rd screen, no such issue would occur.

Is this a bug with the new version of Xcode? I had not noticed this problem previously when navigating via tableviews.

Comment: Can you test, than you are no changing the translucent property of the navigation controller between viewControllers. If you can add this NSLog to both viewWillAppear. NSLog(@"Translucen %ld",self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent);

Comment: Just tested, can confirm, the translucent property is not changing.